# How to create an initializer with dynamicProvider for dark mode

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11, ios-darkmode

Working on support for dark mode I've been able to have dynamic colors that change as you change themes using this pattern:

```swift
static var dynamicColor: UIColor = {
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        return UIColor { (traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIColor in
            switch (traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle, traitCollection.accessibilityContrast) {
            case (.dark, .high):
                return .somethingCustom4

            case (.dark, _):
                return .somethingCustom2

            case (_, .high):
                return .somethingCustom3

            default:
                return .somethingCustom1
            }
        }

    } else {
        return .somethingCustom1
    }
}()
```

I'm trying to simplify the creation of `UIColor` between iOS 12 and 13 with support for dark mode. I came up with a simple `Theme` enum to encapsulate all the logic above and it just exposes 4 cases, so the above declaration simplifies into this:

```swift
static var customColor: UIColor = {
    switch UIColor.theme {
    case .light:
        return somethingCustom1

    case .dark:
        return .somethingCustom2

    case .lightHighContrast:
        return somethingCustom3

    case .darkHighContrast:
        return .somethingCustom4
    }
}()
```

The problem is that while before the simplification everything updated as it should, now the `theme` isn't getting the updated value so the colors do not change. This is how I'm declaring `Theme` with the `init(dynamicProvider:)` initializer, but it seems like `UITraitCollection.current` doesn't have the right value when you switch between dark/light mode:

```swift
public enum Theme {
    case light, dark, lightHighContrast, darkHighContrast

    @available(iOSApplicationExtension 13.0, *)
    init(dynamicProvider: @escaping (UITraitCollection) -> Theme) {
        self = dynamicProvider(UITraitCollection.current)
    }
}

public extension UIColor {
    static var theme: Theme {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return Theme { (traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> Theme in
                switch (traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle, traitCollection.accessibilityContrast) {
                case (.dark, .high):
                    return .darkHighContrast

                case (.dark, _):
                    return .dark

                case (_, .high):
                    return .lightHighContrast

                default:
                    return .light
                }
            }

        } else {
            return .light
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I think that's how that initializer is supposed to work but I haven't been able to find any other examples of this online…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after a lot of messing around I'm still not sure why the original implementation doesn't work, but I did find another way of making it work! So if you're trying to simplify your implementation for support for both iOS 12 and 13, here's what I ended up with:

```swift
public extension UIColor {
    private static func make(dynamicProvider: @escaping (Theme) -> UIColor) -> UIColor {
        guard #available(iOSApplicationExtension 13.0, *) else { return dynamicProvider(.light) }
        return UIColor { (traitCollection) -> UIColor in
            return dynamicProvider(Theme(traitCollection))
        }
    }

    static var customColor: UIColor {
        return .make { (theme) -> UIColor in
            switch theme {
            case .light:
                return .somethingCustom1

            case .dark:
                return .somethingCustom2

            case .lightHighContrast:
                return .somethingCustom3

            case .darkHighContrast:
                return .somethingCustom4
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum Theme {
    case light, dark, lightHighContrast, darkHighContrast

    @available(iOSApplicationExtension 13.0, *)
    init(_ traitCollection: UITraitCollection) {
        switch (traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle, traitCollection.accessibilityContrast) {
        case (.dark, .high):
            self = .darkHighContrast

        case (.dark, _):
            self = .dark

        case (_, .high):
            self = .lightHighContrast

        default:
            self = .light
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That second approach probably works because you stopped using “current” UITraitCollection, which can be undefined in many cases: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection/3238080-current